# How to calculate the coordinate of a point such that this point has a distance x from another point.

Tags: geometry

I have a problem where I have a certain point $A = (1,1,0)$, and from this information I have to determine the coordinate (in a plane xz) of a point B in such a way that distance between A and B is equal to 2.

I tried to match the distance formula to two and put the coordinates of B as variables in this way: $B = (x, 0, z)$.
$$D = \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2+(z_2-z_1)^2}$$
$$2 = \sqrt{(1-x_1)^2+1^2+(z_1)^2}$$

But I did not succeed trying it. I know the right answer is $ B = (\frac {\sqrt{ 2}}2,0,\frac {-\sqrt{2}}2-1)$ but I do not know how to get there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are infinite many points on the $xz$-plane that lie at a distance of $2$ from $A$. In particular, those points lie on a circle centered at $(1,0,0)$ with the radius of $\sqrt{3}$.

Mathematically, your last equation can be rewritten as $$(x-1)^2 + z^2= 3,$$ which is the equation of a circle in the $xz$-plane with radius $\sqrt{3}$ and center $(1,0,0)$.

Comment: But if we take a point Q and a point K different from each other and belonging to the circumference the distance from K to A will not be different from the distance from Q to A? And yet I need to get to that answer I mentioned in the question, the point is that I do not know how to get there.

Comment: Point $B (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0,-1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ is one of the points that lie on the circle. But there are infinite many points that are at a distance of $3$ from $A$. For example, $(1,0,\sqrt{3})$ is at a distance of $2$ from $A$.

Answer (score 0):

The set of points $M$ of the space that satisfies $|AM| = 2$ is the sphere of the center $A$ and of radius $2$. For M(x,y,z) they are described by the equation 
$$(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+z^2= 2^2$$

if in addition, we want points such that y=0 (being in xz plane). the solutions will reduce to points M'(x,0,z) such that 
$$(x-1)^2+z^2= 3$$

This is actually a circle, not a point as pointed by @Math Lover. So there must be some other requirements or some typos in the question. In general, the intersection of a plane and a sphere is a single point if the plan is tangent to the sphere. Otherwise, it is either a circle or the empty set (disjoint). You can use this useful page to verify for your data

http://www.ambrsoft.com/TrigoCalc/Sphere/SpherePlaneIntersection_.htm

you will find the following

[image: numerical result]